# How to create mask for a whole container in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, canvas, phaser-framework, pixi.js

I am trying to create a planet with a background, sphere shadow and a mask, it was pretty straightforward to implement this in Phaser 2, but now it has a bunch of tricky parts for me

Once I update the mask property of my container, nothing is displayed at all. I have already tried several Masks groups, but couldn't succeeded...

In other words: I need to "put" the rectangle background inside of a sphere by using a circle mask

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other better way to do this maybe?

so here is the method I use:

```
init({ x, y, size, sprite, id }) {
    const container = this.scene.add.container(x, y);

    const width = (1200 / 300) * 200;
    const height = 200;

    const earthBMD = this.scene.textures.createCanvas(`earthBMD${id}`, width, height);
    earthBMD.draw(0, 0, this.scene.textures.get(`map-${size}-${sprite}`).getSourceImage());
    const planet = this.scene.add.sprite(0, 0, earthBMD).setOrigin(0.5).setAngle(-15);

    const shadow = this.scene.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sphere').setOrigin(0.5, 0.5).setScale(0.5);

    const mask = this.scene.make.graphics(0, 0).fillStyle(1000000, 0.5).fillCircle(0, 0, 150);

    container.add([planet, mask, shadow]);
    container.mask = new Phaser.Display.Masks.GeometryMask(this.scene, mask);

    return container;
}
```

Comment: Why do you added "pixi.js" tag to this question?

Comment: @domis86 because phaser is based on it

Comment: look here: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/commit/e1c3e6bab3de2af80a935ae850c44101af1be02d#diff-98e64bc1cd2db9333c6effe87bbe0d6dfe8714aba4c6bde45aa037fe0796e44cR24 - it seems Phaser is not using Pixi.js since 2018

Comment: lol @domis86, I was using Phaser in 2014-2016, so I even didn't know :) thank you for the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be pretty easy to create the desired effect *(atleast with this basic GameObjects)*. I'm not sure where your `init` function is inside. If it is in a Scene, you just have to remove the `scene` from `this.scene....`, than it should work. *(and that would be the underlining issue)*

> **p.s.:** don't add the `mask` to the container, like in this line `container.add([planet, mask, shadow]);` except you want the mask Image/Shape to be rendered on the `canvas`.

**here a stripped down example:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.CANVAS,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {

    const container = this.add.container(0, 0);

    const width = config.width;
    const height = config.height;

    let g = this.make.graphics({add:false});
    
    g.fillStyle(0xffff00)
    g.fillRect(10,10, 150, 150);
    
    g.generateTexture('map', 150, 150);

  
    const planet = this.add.sprite(50, 10, 'map')
      .setOrigin(0)

    const mask = this.make.graphics({add:false})
      .fillStyle(1000000, 0.5)
      .fillCircle(0, 0, 200);
    

    container.add([planet]);

    container.mask = new Phaser.Display.Masks.GeometryMask(this, mask);

}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> P.s.: the officials examples are pretty good. Checkout these [examples](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/display/masks/geometry-mask)

Comment: thank you for your reply :) The usage of this.scene is because this is just a different class which has a constructor where I pass the scene value, so that's why I am using it like - this.scene. Actually I tried to do the same above, but I do have the same issue that nothing is displayed :(

Comment: btw, I have just also tried - setMask(mask.createGeometryMask()), but still the same :( I have the same phaser version though

Comment: @biglebowsky19, thanks for your feedback, I have some follow up questions, does the demo work here in the answer, and the examples? Do you have some errors in the browser console? have you removed the mask from the container?

Comment: yeah, it works for me, but I see just a black background with a yellow thingy. No, I don't have any errors in the console for sure. yes for sure I have deleted the mask, so it won't be visible in the container, but now I just don't see anything :( this happens always when I want to add the mask via .mask

Comment: @biglebowsky19 well what you could do, to find the error, is change the `planet` to `const planet = this.scene.add.sprite(0, 0, earthBMD);` (Or even loading a different sprite, maybe one color like in my demo). since rotating might rotate the visible part of the texture outside the screen. (I cant say since I don't know the dimesions of the scene/canvas and `\`map-${size}-${sprite}\``)

Comment: yeah, I thought the same, but that didn't help me :( I was switching them lots of times and couldn't find the issue... alas. but I've just given a try to the rexCircleMaskImage method in rexcirclemaskimageplugin plugin and it works fine... so I will leave it with it :( 

thank you so much for your efforts, help and time, that was very helpful :)

Comment: @biglebowsky19 No problem, rexUi rexRainbow are always a great alternative.